# Propel Migrate Not Generating Diff

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, propel

*Disclaimer*: This may be related to my [other issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20579791/symfony2-command-line-propelsqlinsert-force-failing) with Propel on my computer, but I don't think so, because this command isn't trying to insert anything into the database.

### The Problem

Initially, I generated some SQL and inserted it into the database (manually, due to other issue), and then I changed my XML schema, adding a join table for a many-to-many relationship. When I run `propel:migration:generate-diff`, it prints out the following:

```
Reading databases structure...
3 tables found in all databases.
Loading XML schema files...
4 tables found in 1 schema files.
Comparing models...
Same XML and database structures for all datasource - no diff to generate
```

As far as I can tell, it sees that my database has 3 tables, and my schema file has 4 tables. So, why does it not generate a diff? It sees that there is a difference between the database and the schema, yet it does nothing.

### Possibilities

Here are some possibilities I have considered

- Manually inserting the SQL into the database (due to issue mentioned above) has confused it about what is already there
- There is a bug in the source code causing an issue with migrations AND inserting SQL
- There is something wrong with my environment as I currently have it set up. I have never had an issue with Propel on another machine.

Anyone else experience this issue? Is there a way around this besides manually writing the diffs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after much trial and error, and many unfruitful Google searches, I eventually discovered the problem in a line I missed during the output when running in `--verbose` mode.

The issue was resolved when I changed the file `vendor/propel/propel1/generator/build.properties-example` to `vendor/propel/propel1/generator/build.properies`. I also changed the versions I was using to Phing 2.4.12 and Propel 1.6.9.

Hope this helps someone in the future.